# Remote Control Hotkey default in Windows Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

After selecting to remote control a user, you're given a message box to select what Hot key to use to end the session. In Windows Server 2003 this always defaulted to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and an <kbd>*</kbd>, but in Windows Server 2008 R2 it defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and a <kbd>0</kbd>.

I'm not necessarily picky about what option I use, but for some reason using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> doesn't seem to work for me when trying to end the remote control session. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> on the other hand works every time.

Is there a way to change the default from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default in the registry:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSADMIN]
Example:
-
"ShadowHotkeyShift"=dword:00000002
"ShadowHotkey"=dword:00000023

"ShadowKeyIndex" is the entry index from the drop-down list that pops-up in the Remote Control dialogue